# org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to execute sql

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, flink-table-api

I have a problem running a flink job in mini kube that use table connectors to read messages from kafka  and then tries to write back to kafka (am just trying to learn table api so not doing any analytics) but getting error "org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Failed to execute sql" at ".execute().print()" line in code

```
EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().inStreamingMode().build();
            TableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.create(settings);
        
            String statement = "CREATE TABLE testELink (\r\n" + 
                    "  id STRING,\r\n" + 
                    "  sameAs STRING,\r\n" + 
                    "  modificationType STRING,\r\n" + 
                    "  PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED\r\n" + 
                    ") WITH (\r\n" + 
                    "  'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',\r\n" + 
                    "  'topic' = 'source.test',\r\n" + 
                    "  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka-cp-kafka:9092',\r\n" + 
                    "  'key.format' = 'raw',\r\n" + 
                    "  'value.format' = 'avro-confluent',\r\n" + 
                    "  'value.avro-confluent.url' = 'http://kafka-cp-schema-registry:8081'\r\n" + 
                    ")";
            tEnv.executeSql(statement);

            tEnv.from("testELink").execute().print();
    
            /*sink2*/
             tEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE occurance (\n" +
                        "  id STRING,\r\n" + 
                        "  sameAs STRING \r\n" + 
                        "  modificationType STRING \r\n" + 
                        ") WITH (\n" +
                        "  'connector'  = 'kafka',\n" +
                        "  'topic' = 'source.test.2',\r\n" + 
                        "  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka-cp-kafka:9092',\r\n" + 
                        "  'properties.allow.auto.create.topics' = 'true',\r\n" + 
                        "  'key.format' = 'raw',\r\n" + 
                        "  'value.format' = 'json'\r\n" + 
                        ")");
                    
             Table tab = tEnv.from("testELink");
             tab.executeInsert("occurance");
```

Error is:

```
2022-06-27 13:06:34,066 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.executors.EmbeddedExecutor [] - Submitting Job with JobId=82546596a7b7b0d08a5a91bdcaeb6ffc.
2022-06-27 13:06:34,275 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher     [] - Received JobGraph submission 'collect' (82546596a7b7b0d08a5a91bdcaeb6ffc).
2022-06-27 13:06:34,276 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher     [] - Submitting job 'collect' (82546596a7b7b0d08a5a91bdcaeb6ffc).
2022-06-27 13:06:34,278 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService             [] - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster at akka://flink/user/rpc/jobmanager_11 .
2022-06-27 13:06:34,279 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Initializing job 'collect' (82546596a7b7b0d08a5a91bdcaeb6ffc).
2022-06-27 13:06:34,279 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Using restart back off time strategy NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy for collect (82546596a7b7b0d08a5a91bdcaeb6ffc).
2022-06-27 13:06:34,280 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Running initialization on master for job collect (82546596a7b7b0d08a5a91bdcaeb6ffc).
2022-06-27 13:06:34,280 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Successfully ran initialization on master in 0 ms.
2022-06-27 13:06:34,319 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.adapter.DefaultExecutionTopology [] - Built 1 pipelined regions in 0 ms
2022-06-27 13:06:34,319 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - No state backend has been configured, using default (HashMap) org.apache.flink.runtime.state.hashmap.HashMapStateBackend@15447b8e
2022-06-27 13:06:34,319 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.StateBackendLoader            [] - State backend loader loads the state backend as HashMapStateBackend
2022-06-27 13:06:34,319 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Checkpoint storage is set to 'jobmanager'
2022-06-27 13:06:34,319 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    [] - No checkpoint found during restore.
2022-06-27 13:06:34,319 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Using failover strategy org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.RestartPipelinedRegionFailoverStrategy@339c7d56 for collect (82546596a7b7b0d08a5a91bdcaeb6ffc).
2022-06-27 13:06:34,320 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Starting execution of job 'collect' (82546596a7b7b0d08a5a91bdcaeb6ffc) under job master id 00000000000000000000000000000000.
2022-06-27 13:06:34,321 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinator [] - Starting split enumerator for source Source: KafkaSource-default_catalog.default_database.testELink.
2022-06-27 13:06:34,327 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Starting scheduling with scheduling strategy [org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.strategy.PipelinedRegionSchedulingStrategy]
2022-06-27 13:06:34,327 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Job collect (82546596a7b7b0d08a5a91bdcaeb6ffc) switched from state CREATED to RUNNING.
2022-06-27 13:06:34,328 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Source: KafkaSource-default_catalog.default_database.testELink (1/1) (c3d577b0bcab33a275a7465a3b5ebafa) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
2022-06-27 13:06:34,328 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - ChangelogNormalize(key=[id]) -> NotNullEnforcer(fields=[id]) -> Sink: Collect table sink (1/1) (d9fe6dcb8ae1132ac6a252f6587cc8ff) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
2022-06-27 13:06:34,329 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Connecting to ResourceManager akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*(00000000000000000000000000000000)
2022-06-27 13:06:34,332 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Resolved ResourceManager address, beginning registration
2022-06-27 13:06:34,333 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Registering job manager 00000000000000000000000000000000@akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/jobmanager_11 for job 82546596a7b7b0d08a5a91bdcaeb6ffc.
2022-06-27 13:06:34,332 WARN  org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner [] - Could not execute application: 
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Failed to execute sql
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.tryExecuteJobs(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:84) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.run(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:70) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$handleRequest$0(JarRunHandler.java:104) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604) [?:1.8.0_275]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_275]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to execute sql
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeQueryOperation(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:828) ~[flink-table_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1274) ~[flink-table_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableImpl.execute(TableImpl.java:601) ~[flink-table_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at com.kafkastream.Demo.main(Demo.java:35) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Job client must be a CoordinationRequestGateway. This is a bug.
    at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:138) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.setJobClient(CollectResultFetcher.java:89) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.setJobClient(CollectResultIterator.java:101) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.connectors.CollectDynamicSink$1.setJobClient(CollectDynamicSink.java:73) ~[flink-table_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeQueryOperation(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:813) ~[flink-table_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1274) ~[flink-table_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableImpl.execute(TableImpl.java:601) ~[flink-table_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    at com.kafkastream.Demo.main(Demo.java:35) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.5.jar:1.14.5]
    ... 7 more
2022-06-27 13:06:34,336 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler   [] - Exception occurred in REST handler: Could not execute application.
2022-06-27 13:06:34,336 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Registered job manager 00000000000000000000000000000000@akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/jobmanager_11 for job 82546596a7b7b0d08a5a91bdcaeb6ffc.
2022-06-27 13:06:34,337 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - JobManager successfully registered at ResourceManager, leader id: 00000000000000000000000000000000.
2022-06-27 13:06:34,338 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.DeclarativeSlotManager [] - Received resource requirements from job 82546596a7b7b0d08a5a91bdcaeb6ffc: [ResourceRequirement{resourceProfile=ResourceProfile{UNKNOWN}, numberOfRequiredSlots=1}]
2022-06-27 13:06:34,364 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Source: KafkaSource-default_catalog.default_database.testELink (1/1) (c3d577b0bcab33a275a7465a3b5ebafa) switched from SCHEDULED to DEPLOYING.
2022-06-27 13:06:34,373 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig             [] -
```